# How do I display the name of a deleted element in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I have a simple Rails application where I create objects (such as posts). So far I can edit and delete them, one by one, but now I want to have a `<%= notice %>` *echoing* the name of the deleted object after confirming its deletion. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an extremely common task in Rails, and the idiomatic solution is to forward some data about the deleted record to the subsequent GET request via the [the flash](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash) array.

Your controller's `destroy` action should look something like this:

```
def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.destroy

  redirect_to posts_path, notice: "#{@post.name} was deleted"
end
```

In your index action, you'll be able to access `flash[:notice]` to get the string generated in the previous action.

Comment: that has got to be a milestone!  Congratulations!  Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the details you want to echo (e.g. the name) somewhere, because the object itself will be gone after a redirect. I would use the `flash` for that:

```
# in the controller
def destroy
  thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
  thing.destroy

  redirect_to things_path, :notice => "Thing #{thing.name} was deleted"
end

# in the index view
<% if flash[:notice] %>
  <div class="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `redirect_to posts_path, notice: "#{@post.name} was deleted"` writes to `flash[:notice]` for you.

Comment: @spickermann What's the difference with `.load(params[:id])` instead of `.find(params[:id])`? I tried this but the `load` part says it's a private method, which I just couldn't understand.

Comment: @Zentaurus, I am sorry `load` was just wrong. Use `find` instead.